# Date Validation for parameters in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a requirement where I have been asked to get meaningful error messages out of SSRS reports where user enter the wrong dates like the start date being after the end date . I do not want to lose the calendar box by changing the parameter type. What is the nest way or doing this ? Is there a way of doing it ? Seems SSRS does the parameter validation itself internally so without changing the type of parameter to text and doing some vb code or something in astored procedure you cannot do this . I would be happy if I could just make sure the start date parameter entered was before the end date parameter entered by the user.

Comment: Decided to use a stored procedure for validating input parameters and then use a textbox to be displayed with an error if the condition is met. Working well so far...

Answer (score 0):

Decided to use a stored procedure for validating input parameters and then use a textbox to be displayed with an error if the condition is met. Working well so far..